# MAXIFS to return most recent row given date is less than condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I'm trying to return the most recent entry from A:C using the conditions in E:F.

Bob on 2/28/2021 will return the 2/1/2021 value since 3/1/2021 is after 2/28/2021.

Jerry on 5/14/2021 will return the 5/12/2021 value because 5/14/21 is after 5/12/2021, but before 6/1/2021.

The formula I drafted is very simple, but it is not giving me the right answer for Steve.

```
=MAXIFS($C$2:$C$10,$A$2:$A$10,$E4,$B$2:$B$10,"<"&$F4)
```

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do the return the value in C where the max date that satisfies the criteria is met.  We can do that by sorting the filtered data by the date descending and taking the top value.

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(B:C,(A:A=E2)*(B:B<F2)),1,-1),1,2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in two steps.

1. Find the **max** date that meets your requirements with the following formula in `H2` `=MAXIFS($B$2:$B$10,$A$2:$A$10,E2,$B$2:$B$10,"<"&F2)`
2. Retreive the respective number, e.g. with `=MAXIFS($C$2:$C$10,$A$2:$A$10,E2,$B$2:$B$10,H2)` in `I2`.

There are multiple ways for step 2 and with Office 365 you will not need a helper column, but I wanted to stay closely to your formula.

Comment: Thank you! This worked well. `=MAXIFS($C$2:$C$10,$A$2:$A$10,$E2,$B$2:$B$10,MAXIFS($B$2:$B$10,$A$2:$A$10,$E2,$B$2:$B$10,"<"&$F2))`